# php array filter try to match word the beginning of the values name

Tags: php, array-filter

How can i filter this array values `[Name] =>` try to match word "Good" beginning of the values name

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Good Seat
        [image] => spot
        [category] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Nice Good Service
        [image] => spotless
        [category] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Good Work
        [image] => spotly
        [category] => 1
    )
)
```

I need filter like this

```
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Good Seat
        [image] => spot
        [category] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Good Work
        [image] => spotly
        [category] => 1
    )
)
```

My Code

```
function name($var)
{
    return (is_array($var) && $var['Name'] == preg_match("/^Good/", $var['Name']));
}

print_r(array_filter($var, "name"));
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the $var['Name']=

```
function name($var)
{
    return (is_array($var) && preg_match("/^Good/", $var['Name']));
}
```

Comment: out put show wrong number first `[0]` and then `[2]`

`
Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Good Seat
        [image] => spot
        [category] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Good Work
        [image] => spotly
        [category] => 1
    )
)
`

how to 

Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Good Seat
        [image] => spot
        [category] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Good Work
        [image] => spotly
        [category] => 1
    )
)
`

Comment: result `[0]` then `[2]`
    Array
    (
    
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Good Seat
            [image] => spot
            [category] => 0
        )
    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Good Work
            [image] => spotly
            [category] => 1
        )
    )

need

    Array
    (
    
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Good Seat
            [image] => spot
            [category] => 0
        )
    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Name] => Good Work
            [image] => spotly
            [category] => 1
        )
    )

Answer (score 2):

I would say just do a substr:

```
if ( substr( $var[ 'Name' ], 4 ) == 'Good' ) {
  // do what you want
}
```